# posting form data with javaws in play

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-webservice

Hy, 
I want to do calls to a different rest api from my play application. I'm using the javaws included library.
The specific call requires that I send form data. However I have no idea how I can send the correct data along with my request.
As far as I can see the library only supports sending url-encoded-form-data.
Does anyone know how I can send form-data along with my request like a normal website doing a form submission?

At the moment I have this:

```
Promise<WSResponse> promise = WS.url("http://localhost:"+port+"/login").setContentType("multipart/form-data").post("emailAddress=" + email +"&password=" + password);
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** instead of **multipart/form-data**.

```
Promise<WSResponse> promise = WS.url("http://localhost:"+port+"/login")
                   .setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                   .post("emailAddress=" + email +"&password=" + password);
```